# Using sinon to test a function in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, sinon

I am trying to test mysqlite3 data access layer but I can't seem to correctly stub my db.all() method, I am unsure if this is due to how my database is passed in or whether I am stubbing it wrong.

This is my database file:

```
const db = new sqlite3.Database(path.join(__dirname, ' 
../database/example.db'), (err) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err.message)
    console.log('Connected to the database')
})

module.exports.database = db
```

This is my function I am trying to stub:

```
const db = require('./database.js').database

module.exports.selectMultiple = request => {
    //unimportant code
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err)
            else {
                resolve('blah blah blah')
        })
    })
}
```

This is my attempt which I can't seem to get working:

```
const db = require('../../data_access/database.js').database

describe('select multiple', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const testProduct2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testProduct))
        testProduct2['key'] = '2'
        this.multiple = sinon.stub(db, 'all')
            .resolves([testProduct, testProduct2])
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        this.multiple.restore()
    })

    test('select 2 products', async(done) => {
        expect.assertions(2)
        const macbooks = await productDb.selectMultiple({amount: 2})
        expect(macbooks.length === 2).toBe(true)
        expect(macbooks[0].key !== macbooks[1].key).toBe(true)
        done()
    })
})
```

If I run this the async test block times out. Does anyone know how I should be stubbing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

`db.all` does not return a Promise, it uses a callback as the second argument.

[`stub.resolves`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.1.1/stubs/#stubresolvesvalue) causes the stub to return a Promise so the callback is never called and the Promise returned by `selectMultiple` never resolves causing the test to timeout on `await productDb.selectMultiple({ amount: 2 })`.

### Solution

Stub `db.all` using [`stub.callsArgWith`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.1.1/stubs/#stubcallsargwithindex-arg1-arg2-) so that the callback passed as the second argument is called:

```js
describe('select multiple', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const testProduct2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testProduct))
    testProduct2['key'] = '2'
    this.multiple = sinon.stub(db, 'all')
      .callsArgWith(1, null, [testProduct, testProduct2]);  // use stub.callsArgWith
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    this.multiple.restore()
  })

  test('select 2 products', async () => {
    expect.assertions(2)
    const macbooks = await productDb.selectMultiple({ amount: 2 })
    expect(macbooks.length === 2).toBe(true)  // SUCCESS
    expect(macbooks[0].key !== macbooks[1].key).toBe(true)  // SUCCESS
  })
})
```

Also note that you don't need to use `done` since you are using an `async` test function and are using `await` on the call to `productDb.selectMultiple`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how this works now and where I was going wrong. This answer was very helpful!